# {SwiftUI} Use a button or a stepper to add/remove a view

Tags: uiview, swiftui, uibutton

is it possible to add or remove a view like it can be done in a list?.
I am trying to use a button to do it.

```
@State private var sizebind = 11    
let size = [0, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32]

var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Text("Test")

                Divider().frame(width: 100).padding()
                
                HStack {
                    
                    TextField("Placeholder", text:Value).fixedSize().padding()
                    
                    Picker("RUN", selection: $sizebind)
                    {
                        ForEach(Array(size), id: \.self)
                        {Text("\($0)")}
                    }
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 100).clipped()
                    .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                }
                
                Divider().frame(width: 100).padding()
                
            }
}
```

}
[image: the result]

Comment: What exactly will be deleted on clicking those buttons? The element in picker? Or the entire picker?

Comment: The entire stack; textfield(placeholder) + the picker

Comment: I don’t think that’s an optimal approach to go with, even if it might be possible with custom array of views or some other logic, it’s gone make your code more length and difficult to understand. Deleting picker value with button is still possible without much efforts.

Comment: I see. what approach do you suggest for similar scenarios?